# The joint of two events is less than the marginal?

Tags: probability

Consider two events $A,B$. Is it true that
$$
Pr(A,B)\leq Pr(A)
$$
Can you give some explanations and a counterexample, in case the inequality is not verified?

Comment: Hint: $Pr(A,B)=Pr(B|A)\cdot Pr(A)$. And $0\leq Pr(B|A)\leq 1$

Comment: Hint: the intersection of A and B is a subset of A.

Comment: @callculus why does the conditional probability not exceed 1?

Comment: @drhab Because the intersection of A and B is smaller than A or just A.

Comment: @callculus Exactly. I somehow dislike your hint because it is not more than a reformulation of the problem. Secondly it is possible that conditional probabilities are not yet in the reach of the OP.

Comment: @drhab I used the bayes theorem and the property that every probability is between 0 and 1. Maybe it is too simple for you-but not for me :) An extended version is always possible but I here I kept it short and simple.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a proper answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A\cap B \subseteq A$, and thus $P(A,B)=P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$.